# A question about puzzle books

Tags: discussion

I think the community at P.SE is an *excellent* crowd when one wants to find out good resources for puzzles (/riddles/...). However, as the site policy is rather strict on *opinion based* questions (which therefore don't have a *valid* answer), I'm wondering if the following question category would be suitable for the main site or not:

**Asking for a recommendations for good puzzle books / sites / games...**

I personally think they are within the *scope* of the site, but then again, I'm not sure. So instead of asking them on the main-site, I wanted to poll the general attitude towards such questions here first.

My impression is, that questions like

> "Can you recommend good puzzling books?"

is clearly too broad and invites a VTC immediately (and rightfully so), but if it becomes more specific? For example:

> "I'm interested in logical puzzles and would like to find a book which both offers some non-standard puzzles, but also *teaches* ways to solve them. Can you recommend some resources from your personal experience?"

or

> "Can you suggest good sources for geometry-based puzzles? If possible, can you give details on how 'mathematical' those sources are?"

I *think* such questions would be in the scope of the site, but it might be opening a Pandora's box, so what is the general opinion about such questions here?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you think a good question like this would be?

Comment: @Doorknob冰 Done.

Comment: Those just seem way too broad (they ask for big lists, not answers). If these are going to be "give me a list of books about X," then no, they are not a good fit for Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Doorknob冰 This was my *every-second*-thought, too. But *every-other-second*-thought is: If I'm interested in finding a good list of topical books recommended by the *experts* in this field - isn't asking for exactly this very much in the scope of the site? Say you want to build/learn/study geometrical-puzzles and seek resources for it, wouldn't the 2nd example question be a very reasonable on-topic question? If not, then I think **absolutely no single** "recommendation" question is *not* too broad, as there is *never* a single answer and *always* a list.

Comment: I don't see what you're saying. "Give me a list of sources" is a.) clearly opinion based, b.) asking for *just a list of sources*, c.) outdates very quickly, d.) does not have a single, correct answer, etc.

Comment: @Doorknob冰 Well, that's *very much* what I meant. If you put those arguments as *strict rules* then there simply is *no* recommendation-question which would pass, and the answer to my (posted) question, is simply: **NO**. No need to ask for an example then, is there? But that's why I asked this on meta. || As for a) *sure* b) Not *just* a list. A list *pre-evaluated by experts in the field*. Exactly what I *seek*. c) not really... d) **so what?** It still has answers to be voted for and I can *accept* the one fitting *me* as with all other questions. And *others* can read and like the post.

Comment: Worth reading: [What is the definition of a list question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124450/what-is-the-definition-of-a-list-question) and the [Don't Ask](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) help section (specifically the second part).

Comment: @Emrakul reading both references, I now have *even more* the impression my two example questions would be valid. Was this your intention? If not, I'd welcome some elaboration.

Comment: Way too opinionated.

Comment: @BmyGuest "avoid asking subjective questions where...: every answer is equally valid... there is no actual problem to be solved... you are asking an open-ended question..." - this seems to fit these criteria, which is what I was pointing out.

Comment: I'd vote for the specific version of the question to be in-scope. It's interesting and useful. It 'solves the practical problem' of "where can I find information on X?"

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a great idea. Even if it's not, we can give it a trial run and then ban them as a community when chaos breaks out. It really depends on the answers, which depend on the community.